# How to figure out why I'm getting a NIntegrate::inumr (nonnumeric values) error?

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages

When I execute the following I get an error:

```
NIntegrate[a x, {x, 0, 1}]
```

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand a x has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}.

```
(*  NIntegrate[a x, {x, 0, 1}]  *)
```

How can I figure out why?

Comment: I wrote this so that it might be linked as duplicate in appropriate cases. I was going to make the Q&A CW, but I couldn't find the CW button for the question.

Comment: I've done it. If you want anything of yours wiki'd and you can't do it, just flag.

Comment: @J.M. Thanks.  I'm still wondering whether this Q&A is going to be useful....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to test your integrand `f` and see if it evaluates to a numeric value.
Plug in a numerical value like this:

```
a x /. x -> 0.5
(* 0.5 a *)
```

As you can see it evaluated to `0.5 a`, which contains a `Symbol` and is not a number.  In this case, the problem was an undefined parameter.  Another common issue is an improper function call:

```
f[x_, y_] := x Cos[y];
NIntegrate[f[ReIm[Exp[2 Pi I t]]], {t, 0, 1}]
```

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand f[{Re[E^(2 I π t)],Im[E^(2 I π t)]}] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}.

```
(*  NIntegrate[f[ReIm[Exp[2 π I t]]], {t, 0, 1}]  *)
```

Test the integrand:

```
f[ReIm[Exp[2 Pi I t]]] /. t -> 0.5
(*  f[{-1., 1.22465*10^-16}]  *)
```

The function `f` is called on a `List`, not on the individual coordinates, which does not match its definition.  As a result, it does not evaluate to a numeric value.  (The fix is either to integrate `f @@ ReIm[Exp[2 Pi I t]]` or to change the definition to `f[{x_, y_}] :=...`, but the fix will depend on each particular case.)

Note I plugged in a machine float `0.5` to test the function, not an exact number such as `1/2`.  A machine input should evaluate to a machine number if everything is working.  An exact input will evaluate to an exact expression, which may be as complicated as your integrand: it may be hard to tell if the result is numeric, and if not, you may not see the undefined parameters, such as `a` in the OP.

It's possible to pick a bad number to plug in that results in a numeric error, such as division by zero.  Usually you can try a different number.  When it seems hopeless, you can replace `NIntegate` by `Table` to test many values. This is easily done by copying the input.  You should change the iteration to give several floating-point numbers:

```
Table[a x, {x, 0., 1., 0.1}]
```

You can also try plotting, but you do not see which parameters, function calls or whatever is causing the trouble:

```
Plot[a x, {x, 0, 1}]
```