# NIntegrate allegedly evaluating to non-numerical values

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages, maximum

I'm getting non-numerical-evaluation error messages despite not having any symbolic variables in my code.

Here's a MWE representative of what I'm doing:

```
f[x_,y_]:=NIntegrate[(2y-(x-a/2)^2),{a,0,1}];
FindMaximum[{f[x,0.5],0<x<1},{x,0}]
```

This results in the following error:

> `NIntegrate: The integrand 1.-((-(a/2)+x)^2) has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}.`

I don't see what the problem is. $f$ is clearly a function of $x$ and $y$ and has no non-numerical parameters. I fact, it seems to behave properly other than when I ask it to find the maximum:

```
f[0.2,0.5]
```

> `0.9767`

```
Plot[f[x,0.5],{x,0,1}]
```

> [image]

I've tried adding `?NumericQ` in the function definition as follows, but I get the same result:

```
f[x_,y_?NumericQ]:=NIntegrate[(2y-(x-a/2)^2),{a,0,1}];
```

I've also tried adding `?NumericQ` to to function arguments when I call the function in the `FindMaximum` command, again to no avail:

```
FindMaximum[{f[x,0.5?NumericQ],0<x<1},{x,0}]
```

I had a look at [this Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/151961/how-to-figure-out-why-im-getting-a-nintegrateinumr-nonnumeric-values-error), but my situation doesn't fall into any of the cases described there.

What's going on?

Comment: This works for me: `Clear[f]; f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(2 y - (x - a/2)^2), {a, 0, 1}];`

Comment: Yeah, that works. I didn't realise `?NumericQ` was a per-variable command; I figured adding it once would make it work for all variables of a function. Cheers! (If you can type that as an answer, I can accept that answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Mathematica tries to evaluate `f[x,0.5]` before `x` is defined. This issue is explained clearly in this Wolfram [support page](https://support.wolfram.com/12502).

To force the function to only evaluate if it receives numerical values for both `x` and `y`:

```
Clear[f];
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[(2 y - (x - a/2)^2), {a, 0, 1}]
FindMaximum[{f[x, 0.5], 0 < x < 1}, {x, 0}]
 (* {0.979167, {x -> 0.25}} *)
```

In this particular case, you really only need to restrict `x`:

```
Clear[f];
f[x_?NumericQ, y_] := NIntegrate[(2 y - (x - a/2)^2), {a, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: For comparison, `f[x_, y_] = Integrate[(2 y - (x - a/2)^2), {a, 0, 1}]; Maximize[f[x, 1/2], x]`